# Does tbb_build work on Windows with MSVC?

Tags: c++, cmake, tbb

I have quickly tried the "sub_string_finder" example working with CMake, Visual Studio 2015, Windows, and https://github.com/01org/tbb  (I have Strawberry Perl installed.)

I am attempting to utilize the TBBBuild.cmake
in another project from [this Github repository from intel](https://github.com/01org/tbb/tree/tbb_2017/cmake).
(So I cloned the repository, and trying to run CMake)

My `CMakeLists.txt`  is simple and looks like

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.0.0 FATAL_ERROR)
project(sub_string_finder CXX)

include(${TBB_ROOT}/cmake/TBBBuild.cmake)
# Build Intel TBB with enabled Community Preview Features (CPF).
tbb_build(TBB_ROOT ${TBB_ROOT} CONFIG_DIR TBB_DIR MAKE_ARGS tbb_cpf=1)

#add_executable(sub_string_finder sub_string_finder.cpp)
find_package(TBB REQUIRED tbb_preview)
#target_link_libraries(sub_string_finder ${TBB_IMPORTED_TARGETS})
```

(Note I'm not even doing anything fancy yet like add an executable to test TBB, just trying to `configure` / `generate` a project in CMake. This *should* build the TBB libraries for me, so I can link them later, and all I am trying to do here.)

This the error I get:

```
Building Intel TBB: C:/Strawberry/c/bin/gmake.exe -j16 tbb_build_prefix=tbb_cmake_build_subdir tbb_build_dir=C:/Users/ME/Desktop/TESTTBB/tbb/examples/GettingStarted/sub_string_finder/build/tbb_cmake_build compiler=cl tbb_cpf=1
Building is unsuccessful (2): C:/Users/ME/Desktop/TESTTBB/tbb/./build/Makefile.tbb:32: CONFIG: cfg=debug arch=unknown compiler=cl target=windows runtime=unknown
process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, cl /nologo /Foconcurrent_hash_map.obj /c /MDd /Od /Ob0 /Zi /EHsc /GR /Zc:forScope /Zc:wchar_t /DTBB_USE_DEBUG /D__TBB_LIB_NAME=tbb_preview_debug.lib /DDO_ITT_NOTIFY /GS /DUSE_WINTHREAD /D_CRT_SECURE_NO_DEPRECATE /D_WIN32_WINNT=0x0502 /D__TBB_BUILD=1 /W4 /D__TBB_CPF_BUILD=1 /IC:/Users/ME/Desktop/TESTTBB/tbb/./src /IC:/Users/ME/Desktop/TESTTBB/tbb/./src/rml/include /IC:/Users/ME/Desktop/TESTTBB/tbb/./include C:/Users/ME/Desktop/TESTTBB/tbb/./src/tbb/concurrent_hash_map.cpp, ...) failed.
make (e=2): The system cannot find the file specified.
gmake.exe[1]: *** [C:/Users/ME/Desktop/TESTTBB/tbb/./build/common_rules.inc:76: concurrent_hash_map.obj] Error 2
gmake.exe: *** [Makefile:32: tbb] Error 2
```

So it is not getting past the

```
tbb_build(TBB_ROOT ${TBB_ROOT} CONFIG_DIR TBB_DIR MAKE_ARGS tbb_cpf=1)
```

line of the CMakeLists file.
Inside the TBBBuild there look to be hooks for windows, MSVC, but still having issues with this basic example.

I call the command with the basic
    cmake -DTBB_ROOT=c:/libraries/tbb
(where I cloned TBB)

Comment: Why do you want to compile TBB yourself and not just use the compiled version available [here](https://github.com/01org/tbb/releases)?

Comment: yes I want to compile it myself inside another project as a dependency

Comment: It looks like you have not a `cl` compiler in your environment
`make` can't create a process: `process_begin: CreateProcess(NULL, cl /nologo /Foconcurrent_hash_map.obj ...`